# How to check if device online all the time in the background using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a mobile application that is created with flutter, the application is some kind of a client that is comminuting with a server. I want to add something that checks for the device if it is connected.

**How to works** :

When the first time used the application, the users add urls of the server and it is registered in the server sending its own Mac-address and assigning an ID to the device.

**what I need to do** :

We need to know all the time if the device connected or not.

**What I've done** :

Sending Http post request every few seconds with the mac_address in the body, as long as the app is connected and running. But that is very exhausting for connection and server, and even the device itself. any other solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to tell if the device is connected to the Internet or trying to make a persistent connection to the database?

Comment: @Jwildsmith Trying to tell that the device is connected and the app is open on it